# Handling start and finish of request in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I write a serviceHelper in angular 6. I want to show loading image for every request start and close loading image when request finish automatically. So, I need to eventHandler for request when catch to start and finish of request. (Maybe catch error). I create a loader interceptor. But, interceptor not catch my requests.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import ServiceResult from '../models/common/service-result';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceHelper {    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get<T>(modulePort, controllerName: string, methodName: string, params: HttpParams = null): Observable<ServiceResult<T>> {
      return this.http.get<ServiceResult<T>>("http://localhost:5001/api/" + controllerName + "/" + methodName, { params: params });
    }

  post<T>(modulePort, controllerName: string, methodName: string, postedObject): Observable<ServiceResult<T>> {
    return this.http.post<ServiceResult<T>>("http://localhost:5001/api/" + controllerName + "/" + methodName, postedObject);
  }
}
```

ServiceResult.ts

```
abstract class ServiceResult<T> {
  public abstract messages: string[];
  public abstract resultType: int;
  public abstract data: T;
}

export default ServiceResult;
```

loader-interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { ServiceHelper } from '../helpers/service-helper';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private currentRequests: number;
  constructor(
    private _httpService: ServiceHelper) {
  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    debugger;
    if (this._httpService.ukljuciLoader) {
      console.log("Your request started");
      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            console.log("Your request finished");
            }
          }, (err: any) => {
            console.log("You get an error.");
          })
        );
    } else {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }
}

export const LoaderInterceptorProvider = {
  provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
  useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
  multi: true
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create interceptor for that purpose. This is mine:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';
import { HttpService } from '../shared/http.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private currentRequests: number;
    constructor(
        private _loaderService: LoaderService,
        private _httpService: HttpService) {
        this.currentRequests = 0;
    }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (this._httpService.ukljuciLoader) {
            if (this._loaderService.autoloader) {
                this.incrementRequestCount();
            }
            return next.handle(request)
                .pipe(
                    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            if (this._loaderService.autoloader) {
                                this.decrementRequestCount();
                            }
                        }
                    }, (err: any) => {
                        if (this._loaderService.autoloader) {
                            this.currentRequests = 0;
                            this._loaderService._toggleLoader.emit(false);
                        }
                    })
                );
        } else {
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
    private decrementRequestCount() {
        if (--this.currentRequests === 0) {
            this._loaderService._toggleLoader.emit(false);
        }
    }

    private incrementRequestCount() {
        if (this.currentRequests++ === 0) {
            this._loaderService._toggleLoader.emit(true);
        }
    }
}

export const LoaderInterceptorProvider = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: LoaderInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

This is html:

```
<div class="loader-wrapper" *ngIf="loader">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

and this is ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LoaderService } from './loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html'
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public loader = false;
  constructor(
    private _loaderService: LoaderService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._loaderService._toggleLoader
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          setTimeout(() => { this.loader = res; });
        });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
}
```

loader service:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {
    public autoloader = true;
    public _toggleLoader: EventEmitter<any>;
    constructor() {
        this._toggleLoader = new EventEmitter<any>();
    }
    toggleLoader(toggle: boolean) {
        this._toggleLoader.emit(toggle);
    }
}
```

app module

```
....
import { LoaderInterceptor, LoaderInterceptorProvider } from './loader/loader.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    LoaderModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
   ...
    LoaderInterceptorProvider,
    ...
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [..],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

finnaly css

```
.loader-wrapper {
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  z-index: 9998;
}
.loader {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  margin: -10vw 0 0 -10vw; 
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #3498db;
  border-bottom-color: #3498db; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}  
.loader:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:2%;
  bottom: 2%;
  left: 2%;
  right: 2%; 
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top-color: #db213a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 3s linear infinite; 
}  
.loader:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  right: 5%; 
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #dec52d;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;
}  
  /*Keyframes for spin animation */  
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}  
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}  
@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}  
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(0deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(180deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);  /* IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(360deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
  }
}
```

### When you don't want to star loader

This is my http.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Url } from './global';

export interface IRequestOptions {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    observe?: 'body';
    params?: HttpParams;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
    body?: any;
}

export function httpServiceCreator(http: HttpClient) {
    return new HttpService(http);
}

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    ukljuciLoader: boolean;
    public constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        // If you don't want to use the extended versions in some cases you can access the public property and use the original one.
        // for ex. this.httpClient.http.get(...)
    }

    public get<T>(url: string, options?: IRequestOptions, loader: boolean = true): Observable<T> {
        this.ukljuciLoader = loader;
        return this.http.get<T>(Url + url, options);
    }

    public post<T>(url: string, params: Object, options?: IRequestOptions, loader: boolean = true): Observable<T> {
        this.ukljuciLoader = loader;
        return this.http.post<T>(Url + url, params, options);
    }

    public put<T>(url: string, params: Object, options?: IRequestOptions, loader: boolean = true): Observable<T> {
        this.ukljuciLoader = loader;
        return this.http.put<T>(Url + url, params, options);
    }

    public delete<T>(url: string, options?: IRequestOptions, loader: boolean = true): Observable<T> {
        this.ukljuciLoader = loader;
        return this.http.delete<T>(Url + url, options);
    }
}
export const HttpServiceProvider = {
    provide: HttpService,
    useFactory: httpServiceCreator,
    deps: [HttpClient]
};
```

And this is call when I want loader started:

```
someCall( userid: number) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(userid: userid );
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this._http.post<any>('serverapi/spme call', bodyString, { headers: headers });
    }
```

This is when I don't want loader to start:

```
someCall( userid: number) {
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(userid: userid );
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
        return this._http.post<any>('serverapi/spme call', bodyString, { headers: headers }, false);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JoeBelladonna. I tried interceptor before asking question. But I can't achieve use with my serviceHelper. My main problem is create interceptor which my serviceHelper can use.

Comment: @Hasan Ozdemir If you create interceptor, every http request from any service will use it. It is working "automatically" there is no need to call it specifically in any service.

Comment: Ok.I understand. I was thinking that i must call. But, I want only "Post","Put", and "Delete". Not "Get". How can I except "Get" request. @JoeBelladonna

Comment: @Hasan Ozdemir I will edit my anwser and will show you how you can send command not to start loader. Just in sec

Comment: I edited my question @JoeBelladonna. And I add my loader-interceptor.ts. But interceptor  didn't catch my requests automatically as you said. Where is my mistake?

Comment: My mistake is because of injecting app.module.ts with mistake. Your code worked. Thanks @JoeBelladonna

Answer (score 2):

> This is the best schenario where you can use `HttpInterceptor`.

### LoaderInterceptorService

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.showLoader();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => { 
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.onEnd();
      }
    },
      (err: any) => {
        this.onEnd();
    }));
  }
  private onEnd(): void {
    this.hideLoader();
  }
  private showLoader(): void {
   //show the image here
  }
  private hideLoader(): void {
   //hide the image
  }
}
```

### AppModule

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoaderInterceptorService } from './_services/loader-interceptor.service';
...
providers: [
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: LoaderInterceptorService,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SunilSingh. I tried interceptor before asking question. But I can't achieve use with my serviceHelper. My main problem is create interceptor which my serviceHelper can use.

Comment: It looks like you have missed some configured. Could you share what you have done and what you have missed. This looks lengthy solution at first glance but it does magic in long run.

Comment: I added your httpInterceptor. And my providers is like that in my app.module.ts:    providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    AuthGuard, LoaderInterceptorService
  ],

Answer (score 0):

You should use subscribe to angular http service result. 
Sample for your code;

```
get<T>(modulePort, controllerName: string, methodName: string, params: HttpParams = null): Observable<ServiceResult<T>> {
      return this.http.get<ServiceResult<T>>("http://localhost:5001/api/" + controllerName + "/" + methodName, { params: params }).subscribe(result=>result.json(), err=> console.log(err));
    }
```

and you can look for this git repo which contains http wrapper like yours;
https://github.com/mehmetkarpuz/Angular6-http-wrapper

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mehmet. I think HttpInterceptor is better way for this purpose.